# Error fatal en servidor MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una situación con el servidor de `MySQL` y tengo que reinstalar pero no tengo respaldo de mis *Bases de Datos*. Solo tengo los archivos que se generan en:

> C:\xampp\mysql\data

```
db.opt
.ibd
.frm
```

¿Hay alguna forma de recuperar mis bases?